# Name mangling of c++ classes and its member functions?

Tags: c++

Is there no way I could avoid name mangling of C++ classes and its member functions when exposed from a c++ dll.

Can't I use a def file mechanism in this regard ?

Comment: But why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is not on purpose .. I was just curious to see if I could use my exported classes on any other vendor where linker would do the mangling in its own ways . :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to provide C wrappers around the C++ library. This was quite popular 10 or more years back when I was programming in C++ but I don't know if it is done any more.

Basically, for every `class C`, for every constructor `ctor` to be exposed to create an `extern "C" CPtr cCtor(....)` method that returns an opaque pointer `CPtr` and for every function `func` to be exposed you create `extern "C" cFunc(CPtr,....)`

Another approach is to create a `CStruct` that has member variables of function pointer types, implement them to call the class methods and let the client do all the hard work.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe so. Name mangling is used so that each overloaded function has a different name as viewed by the linker.

You could rewrite them in C and use the `extern "C" {}` construct but then you lose all your beautiful inheritance, polymorphism and so forth. You could also wrap the C++ inside C functions and expose only the C functions.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could think of is declaring functions as extern "C". The name mangling is required for the linker to distinguish e.g. overloaded functions by their parameter list (which would be unavailable to the linker if not for name mangling).

Answer (score 0):

Virtual function would be the answer I think, have you noticed COM, create a instance, it gives you a pointer to that interface represented as class. I guess that methods declared are not resolved by name,
but by slot index.