# Unmangling of functions not working in Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, cuda, thrust

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Name mangling of c++ classes and its member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576767/name-mangling-of-c-classes-and-its-member-functions)

I created a Visual C++ dll. It is working and i can call my Thrust methods from cuda through this dll in c#.

The only problem is, that i am not able to unmangle the function names. I would like to have the normal names so i would not need to use an Entrypoint with the convention.

Here is my code. 
This is my header

```
//ThrustCH.h
    #pragma once
    enter code here__declspec(dllexport) class ThrustFuncs 
    {
        __declspec(dllexport) static int maxValueThrust(int *data, int N);
        __declspec(dllexport) static double maxValueThrust(double *data, int N);
        __declspec(dllexport) static int* sort(int* data, int N);
        __declspec(dllexport) static double* sort(double* data, int N);
        __declspec(dllexport) static int simple(int N);
    };
```

This is my cpp

```
// thrustDLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "thrustH.h"
#include "thrustCH.h"

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int ThrustFuncs::maxValueThrust(int *data, int N){
        return thrustH::maxValue(data,N);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) double ThrustFuncs::maxValueThrust(double *data, int N){
        return thrustH::maxValue(data,N);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) int* ThrustFuncs::sort(int* data, int N){
        return thrustH::sort(data,N);
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) double* ThrustFuncs::sort(double* data, int N){
        return thrustH::sort(data,N);
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) int ThrustFuncs::simple(int N){
        return N;
    }
}
```

I tried to use extern "C" and __declspec(dllexport) almost everywhere put i guess I'm doing something wrong. Could you help me please?

Comment: If you want your functions to be exported with C names, why do you wrap them in a class ?

Comment: I don't understand. Is this not allowed? It makes my code in the DLL clearer. How else should i do it?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11798061/279259) below.

Comment: Could you tell me how it should look like giving one example with a method?

Comment: To call a method you need an instance of the class, so just create one. Perhaps you were talking about "static methods" ? If so, its very similar to the `namespace` case. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to export C++ functions but want them to have a C name.

There is no direct way to do that, mainly because it doesn't make sense.

`C` doesn't have classes (or namespaces for that matter) and those usually are involved in the C++ name mangling. That is, don't write the functions you intend to export with a `C` name decoration in a `class` declaration.

You can, however, still write C functions (in an `extern "C"` block) in which you call your C++ functions, methods, or classes.

Something like:

```
class foo
{
  static int bar(const std::string& str) { return static_cast<int>(str.size()); }
}

extern "C"
{
  int bar(const char* str)
  {
    // Call C++ version of the function.
    try
    {
      return foo::bar(str);
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
      // Handle it somehow
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: got i working thx. Calling the C++ from C was the answer. But i neaded to create a new .cpp file to where i put only the C code. Don't know why but it works now :D

Comment: Glad you succeeded. Putting them in another file is probably cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `__cdecl` for the functions that you want to export which will not mangle the names.

Refer: [/Gd, /Gr, /Gz (Calling Convention)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx)

Comment: I tried int __cdecl ThrustFuncs::maxValueThrust(int *data, int N) but i doesn't work. still mangled